# C# - Long to Hex conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `long` data type to HexString but I am not getting expected result.

Here is the code

```
var hexNumber = "ABCDEFAB";
long ? decimalNumber = 0;
int decNum = 0;
var isNumber = int.TryParse(hexNumber, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decNum);
```

And this is the result I get

```
"FFFFFFFFABCDEFAB"
```

I also created a **[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lM8KQH)**

Comment: Now try with `7BCDEFAB`. What do you see? Magic number is `7FFFFFFF` :)

Comment: int.TryParse will try to put that hex string in an integer value (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)... your 'ABCDEFAB' results in 2,882,400,171.. you just get an overflow...

Comment: +1 the explanation is really helpful.. What if I use `uint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be just me, but shouldn't your

```
var isNumber = int.TryParse(hexNumber, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decNum);
```

be a

```
long.TryParse(hexNumber, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decNum);
```

statement?

Comment: `decNum` also should be a long.

Comment: This should probably be reworded to look more like an answer instead of a comment on the question.

Comment: I don't have the ability to comment. Need 50 rep.

Comment: Make sure that you change decNum as well as Ilya pointed out. :)